# Is there more, less, or equal overhead for elisp, as for a bash script, to call awk, ps, etc?

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, resources

Hopefully the question explains itself well enough. I'm referring to exta time and system resources involved for one vs. the other... I tend to think it would be the same, but I want to go beyond just think. Do the both make the same system calls?

Comment: You seem to be asking two separate questions -- one, are the overheads the same, two, are the system calls the same... the answer doesn't have to be the same to both of them.

Comment: I'm basically just wondering if calling `awk` or a `bash` script from `elisp` is going to slow things down more than if I was making similar calls from a bash script.. I've just started elisp-ing and wondered if, for example, bash-calling-bash skips the need to load the bash interpreter, but emacs-calling-bash must load it.. Maybe that's the only time it makes a difference (or maybe there is no difference?) ... The more I think about it, it seems that calling `awk` for example, would be the same from either *bash* or *elisp*.. so it is probably a quetion about what happens when bash calls bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will highly depend on what is happening on the system *besides* your `elisp` program running, because the `bash` program (and all required libs) may or may not be cached at that moment in time. Same goes for `awk`. In the case where you call `bash` from `bash`, the `bash` *must* already have been loaded into memory.

Comment: Okay, thanks.. so there's nothing dramatically different going on.. It is just one interpreted language calling another.. I think I'm still getting my head around the fact that elisp is not an addon language subordinate to the editor, but rather the editor is an *awk* or *python* program :), well, you know what I mean: the *awk/python* just happens to be *elisp* in this case, and emacs is a script... all of which puts elisp on an even keel with other languages. Got it!